# How do i change the directory from which i import modules?

Tags: python

I tried using `pip` to install some packages, and I found that they are installed to `C:\Users\joaqu\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages`.

Now I want to use Visual Studio 2022 to run my Python code that imports that module. But it fails with an error that says "No module named '(module name)'".

How do I fix this?

Comment: the road that you'd go down to fix this is so long and frustrating (so long that I forgot how to even fix it), that you're just better off uninstalling pip and python, and reinstalling python and getting anaconda. Anaconda is a package manager that takes care of stuff like this

Comment: Do you mean [Visual Studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) or [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/)? They are 2 completely different IDEs, despite being similarly named. If this is VS Code, read their docs on Python environments: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments. If you know the path to your site-packages directory, you need to tell your IDE to look for it there.

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch ...you still have to tell the IDE to look for the packages in the directories where Anaconda installed them.

Comment: **Do not** try to fix this by changing the import path. Fix it by *making sure that you run the same copy of Python that Pip is installing to*, or conversely by *making sure that you run the copy of Pip that belongs to the Python you want to run*.

Comment: @NicholasHansen-Feruch That is **absolutely not true**. The problems are easy to fix, and easy to explain how to fix - just that if you want to use an IDE, there are steps that are IDE-dependent (and which you can **not avoid** by using Anaconda). Furthermore, on systems that are not Windows, attempting to uninstall the Python that comes with the computer can *seriously damage the operating system*.

Comment: Conda is an entirely separate ecosystem that has to be learned from scratch and requires a whole parallel set of documentation (the PyPI Packaging Authority teaches how to use `pip` and the corresponding built-in tools). Conda may seem more straightforward to use, but a lot of that just boils down to avoiding the "install packages to the wrong Python installation" by only having one Python installation that Conda knows about. Every Python comes with its own Pip module and corresponding wrapper executable - that's *how it's designed to work*; using **that** Pip installs to **that** Python.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the IDE is using a different installation of Python than the one you want to use. (It may have come with the IDE.)

In this case you need to know how to change the interpreter in the IDE that you use or how to install packages in the IDE's version of Python.

in Visual Studio Code, you can go to to File -> Preferences -> Settings, write `python` in the search area, and copy and paste the path for the Python that you want into the `Python: Default Interpreter Path` field.

[image: image to make every thing clear]